# linq count returns 0 if the group by column is 0

Tags: vb.net, linq, byte

I have a LINQ query that is working for everything except for when the location is 0 and I want a count of how many, the `Inventory = locGroup.Count` line returns 0. All of the other Count functions work fine when the location is 0 and the `Inventory = locGroup.Count` works fine when the location isn't 0. As far as I can tell you can't debug a LINQ statement in VS so I'm not sure why or how this isn't working.

Not sure how to display this tabular data on SO

IMLOCN | IMPRIC | isSpecial | vehComments | numPics | Age

50--------------5------------0---------------Y-----------------21-------100

50--------------5.8----------1---------------Y-----------------23-------200

0---------------2-------------0---------------N-----------------0---------5

0---------------4-------------0---------------N-----------------0---------10

Expected output

50 -- 2 -- 2 -- 1 -- 2 -- 2 -- 300

0 -- 2* -- 2 -- 0 -- 0 -- 0 -- 15  *actual results this is a 0 but other #'s stay the same.

```
Dim summaryInfo = From p In infoTable
    Group p By Location = p.Field(Of Byte)("IMLOCN") Into locGroup = Group
         Select New With {
                Key locGroup,
                    .Location = locGroup.Max(Function(r) r.Field(Of Byte)("IMLOCN")),
                    .Inventory = locGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of Byte)("IMLOCN")),
                    .Priced = locGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of Decimal)("IMPRIC") > 0),
                    .Special = locGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of Boolean)("isSpecial") = True),
                    .Commented = locGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("vehComments") = "Y"),
                    .Pictures = locGroup.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("numPics") > 0),
                    .Age = locGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("AGE"))
         }
```

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: I was able to get what I needed by saying locGroup.Count() and leaving out the anonymous function but that doesn't answer my question of why it wasn't working the way it was for a locGroup = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to replicate your query in C#, and this is what I used:

```
var infoTable=new []{
 new { IMLOCN=50,IMPRIC=5.0,isSpecial=false,vehComments="Y",numPics=21,Age=100 },
 new { IMLOCN=50,IMPRIC=5.8,isSpecial=true,vehComments="Y",numPics=23,Age=200 },
 new { IMLOCN=0,IMPRIC=2.0,isSpecial=false,vehComments="N",numPics=0,Age=5 },
 new { IMLOCN=0,IMPRIC=4.0,isSpecial=false,vehComments="N",numPics=0,Age=10 }
};

var summaryInfo = infoTable
  .GroupBy(i=>i.IMLOCN)
  .Select(locGroup=> new {
    Location=locGroup.Max(l=>l.IMLOCN),
    Inventory=locGroup.Count(l=>l.IMLOCN>0),
    Priced=locGroup.Count(l=>l.IMPRIC>0),
    Special=locGroup.Count(l=>l.isSpecial),
    Commented=locGroup.Count(l=>l.vehComments=="Y"),
    Pictures=locGroup.Count(l=>l.numPics>0),
    Age=locGroup.Sum(l=>l.Age)
});
```

with this result:

[image]

Not being a VB.NET expert (and I rarely use query syntax), I was a little confused by this clause: `Location = p.Field(Of Byte)("IMLOCN")`.  Is that a comparision, or is that trying to set a temp variable called Location?  This line: `Location=locGroup.Max(l=>l.IMLOCN)` is a direct translation, but I would typically use `Location=locGroup.Key` instead since it's the group key. **In my attempts, it didn't like `Inventory=locGroup.Count(l=>l.IMLOCN)` saying that it couldn't convert IMLOCN to a boolean, which leads me to the conclusion that you are implicitly converting IMLOCN to a boolean, and since 0 is false, it doesn't count them.**

TLDR:  `.Count(lambda)` takes a lamda expression that returns true/false to determine if that record should be counted or not.  It is implicitly converting IMLOCN to a boolean for you, and since 0 converts to false, it isn't counting those records.  In essence, the code you have isn't counting the number of IMLOCN's, it is counting the number of IMLOCN's that when coverted to a boolean are true.  If all you want to know is how many records are in the group, then `.Count()` is what you want.

Comment: As a side note, you might consider looking at a program called [LINQpad](https://www.linqpad.net/).  It allows you to play with LINQ queries and see the results in a clear and easy fashion.  For example, I think if you ran `infoTable.GroupBy(i=>i.IMLOCN).Dump()` (or the equivalent in VB) you would quickly see what that returns and what the following `.Select` is working with.  It helps visualize what is actually going on in your query in each step, especially as you are learning LINQ.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it makes sense. I'm not a VB guy at all and was just trying to fix a legacy application. I'll have to download LINQpad so one day I'll be able to answer SO questions instead of just asking them.